# Java string comparison not working as intended

Tags: java, android

I've done quite a bit of string comparisons in java in the past, but this time it doesn't seem to work. 
I'm aware of the fact, that you have to use the `.equals()` function in order to compare strings in java.


In my attempt to figure out what's wrong, I wrote the following code snippet: 
 `Log.e("testLogic", String.valueOf(taken.getText().toString().trim().equals('1')));
 Log.e("testValue", taken.getText().toString().trim());`
producing the following result:

```
E/testLogic﹕ false
E/testValue﹕ 1
E/testLogic﹕ false
E/testValue﹕ 1
E/testLogic﹕ false
E/testValue﹕ 0
```

This seems rather strange, since the two first 'testLogic' logs should produce true.

The code is used in a custom list adapter if it means anything.


/Mikkel

Comment: `'1'` is a `char`, not a `String`.  It is not unusual behavior for an `equals()` method to return false if you hand it some other class.

Comment: You're comparing a (single character) String with a char.

Comment: Replace `'1'` with `"1"` in other words.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I must be more tired than I thought. Anyways, thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not comparing 2 `Strings`. You have to put it like this:

```
Log.e("testLogic", String.valueOf(taken.getText().toString().trim().equals("1")));
```

because `.equals()` function needs two `Strings`. Supposing that `s1` and `s2` are `Strings`, you should do:

```
s1.equals(s2);
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

The `.equals()` comes from the `Object` class. Each class inherit it from the `Object` class. `String` class also inherited it from the `Object` class and override it like this -

```
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = count;
            if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
  }
```

And `String` has not any overloaded version of `equals` method for `char`. You can see if `String`'s `.equals()` method takes any object but it returns `false` when it is any type rather than `String`. It only returns `true` if the provided parameter is of type `String` and is meaningfully equals. So you have to write -

```
Log.e("testLogic",String.valueOf(taken.getText().toString().trim().equals("1")));
```

instead of -

```
Log.e("testLogic", String.valueOf(taken.getText().toString().trim().equals('1')));
```